# loop function i r code for large data file

Tags: r, loops, biomart

I am having same issue [Query genes within regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136262/query-genes-within-regions/50150576#50150576) but data is huge and creating certain issue.
My data is like

```
1    10000    11000
1    20000    21000
.    .       .
.    .       .
.    .       .
1    1000000    1001000
```

.    .       .

d<-read.table("1.txt")

```
library(biomaRt)

ensembl = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "sscrofa_gene_ensembl")



    res <- cbind(
      d,
      genes = apply(d, 1, function(i){
        x <- getBM(attributes=c("external_gene_name"), 
                   filters = c("chromosome_name" , "start", "end"), 
                   values = list(i[1], i[2], i[3]), 
                   mart = ensembl)
        # keeping only 3 genes, as output is too long.
        # In your case remove below line
        x <- head(x, 3)
    
        # return genes, comma separated
        paste(x$external_gene_name, collapse = ",")
      })
    )

res
```

My query is can we make loop in this code and print gene name. for certain interval of run.

Comment: (1) How big is "huge"? (2) Using `apply` on a whole frame can be costly if you have non-`numeric` data in it: it always converts the frame to a `matrix`, which converts if not all the same `class`. (It can be costly anyway with large-ish frames, as it'll make a copy regardless.) (3) If your data really is "large", you might benefit from using `data.table`, as it tends to be more memory-frugal (and faster, when used correctly).

Comment: no of queries are more than 25000. I have tested the code on 500 queries and it works pretty smoothly. Means read my file using data.table? Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: the `biomaRt` API for R is very slow and hates big queries. I highly advise using `ensembldb` for this

Comment: 25000 is not near a limit where I would expect huge performance problems in base R `data.frame` work. FYI, `data.table` is effectively a dialect of R that works solely frames that make changes in-place, made more meaning to know that many/most operations on data.frames make complete copies, either of individual columns or of the whole frame, often for the sole purpose of changing a subset of one column.

Answer (score 1):

`ensembldb` will make a local ensembl database that will be very easy to query. I also quite like `plyranges`, which allows us to make joins using SQL-like (and dplyr-like) language for `GenomicRanges` objects, which are the default Bioconductor class for genomic coordinates.

First, we'll call/install the necessary packages:

```
if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages("tidyverse")
if(!require(AnnotationHub)) BiocManager::install("AnnotationHub")
if(!require(ensembldb)) BiocManager::install("ensembldb")
if(!require(plyranges)) BiocManager::install("plyranges")
```

Here, I query `AnnotationHub` to find the particular database we want to download, then we download it.

```
ah <- AnnotationHub()
#> snapshotDate(): 2020-04-27
query <- query(ah, "EnsDb", "Sus scrofa")
tibble(id = query$ah_id, title = query$title) %>%
    dplyr::filter(str_detect(title, "Sus scrofa"))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   id      title                           
#>   <chr>   <chr>                           
#> 1 AH64991 Ensembl 94 EnsDb for Sus scrofa 
#> 2 AH68020 Ensembl 95 EnsDb for Sus scrofa 
#> 3 AH69274 Ensembl 96 EnsDb for Sus scrofa 
#> 4 AH73969 Ensembl 97 EnsDb for Sus scrofa 
#> 5 AH75101 Ensembl 98 EnsDb for Sus scrofa 
#> 6 AH78892 Ensembl 99 EnsDb for Sus scrofa 
#> 7 AH79797 Ensembl 100 EnsDb for Sus scrofa
edb <- ah[["AH79797"]]
#> loading from cache
```

Here I made a little example GRanges object:

```
#-- Example data
gen_regions <- data.frame(chr = c(1,1,1,2), 
                          start = c(10000, 20000, 1000000,0),
                          end = c(11000, 21000, 1001000,100000)) %>%
    GRanges()
```

Then, we get `genes` from our ensembl database. You can replace here by `transcripts` which will be less stringent.

```
genes <- genes(edb)
```

Finally, one step join our genomic regions and the annotated genes information:

```
gene_overlap <- join_overlap_left(gen_regions, genes)
gene_overlap
#> GRanges object with 12 ranges and 8 metadata columns:
#>        seqnames          ranges strand |            gene_id   gene_name
#>           <Rle>       <IRanges>  <Rle> |        <character> <character>
#>    [1]        1     10000-11000      * | ENSSSCG00000037372            
#>    [2]        1     20000-21000      * | ENSSSCG00000037372            
#>    [3]        1 1000000-1001000      * |               <NA>        <NA>
#>    [4]        2        0-100000      * | ENSSSCG00000014554            
#>    [5]        2        0-100000      * | ENSSSCG00000014555        ODF3
#>    ...      ...             ...    ... .                ...         ...
#>    [8]        2        0-100000      * | ENSSSCG00000014565            
#>    [9]        2        0-100000      * | ENSSSCG00000014558       SIRT3
#>   [10]        2        0-100000      * | ENSSSCG00000014559      PSMD13
#>   [11]        2        0-100000      * | ENSSSCG00000014561       NLRP6
#>   [12]        2        0-100000      * | ENSSSCG00000025023       PGGHG
#>          gene_biotype seq_coord_system
#>           <character>      <character>
#>    [1] protein_coding       chromosome
#>    [2] protein_coding       chromosome
#>    [3]           <NA>             <NA>
#>    [4] protein_coding       chromosome
#>    [5] protein_coding       chromosome
#>    ...            ...              ...
#>    [8] protein_coding       chromosome
#>    [9] protein_coding       chromosome
#>   [10] protein_coding       chromosome
#>   [11] protein_coding       chromosome
#>   [12] protein_coding       chromosome
#>                                                                                 description
#>                                                                                 <character>
#>    [1]                                                                                 NULL
#>    [2]                                                                                 NULL
#>    [3]                                                                                 <NA>
#>    [4]                    secretoglobin family 1C member 1 [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:100517148]
#>    [5]                  outer dense fiber of sperm tails 3 [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:100499231]
#>    ...                                                                                  ...
#>    [8]          interferon-induced transmembrane protein 1 [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:100127358]
#>    [9]                                           sirtuin 3 [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:100125971]
#>   [10]               proteasome 26S subunit, non-ATPase 13 [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:100517815]
#>   [11]                NLR family pyrin domain containing 6 [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:100519245]
#>   [12] protein-glucosylgalactosylhydroxylysine glucosidase [Source:NCBI gene;Acc:100518005]
#>             gene_id_version      symbol            entrezid
#>                 <character> <character>              <list>
#>    [1] ENSSSCG00000037372.2                              NA
#>    [2] ENSSSCG00000037372.2                              NA
#>    [3]                 <NA>        <NA>                    
#>    [4] ENSSSCG00000014554.4                       100517148
#>    [5] ENSSSCG00000014555.4        ODF3           100499231
#>    ...                  ...         ...                 ...
#>    [8] ENSSSCG00000014565.3             100519082,100127358
#>    [9] ENSSSCG00000014558.4       SIRT3           100125971
#>   [10] ENSSSCG00000014559.4      PSMD13           100517815
#>   [11] ENSSSCG00000014561.5       NLRP6           100519245
#>   [12] ENSSSCG00000025023.3       PGGHG           100518005
#>   -------
#>   seqinfo: 2 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

This table is already in "tidy" format, but you may want to summarize it to have a single row for each region. Here's a suggestion of how to do that:

```
per_region_genes <- gene_overlap %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(gene_name = ifelse(gene_name == "", NA, gene_name)) %>%
    group_by(seqnames, start, end) %>%
    summarize(gene_ids = paste(na.exclude(gene_id), collapse = ", "),
              gene_names = paste(na.exclude(gene_name), collapse = ", "), .groups = "drop")
per_region_genes
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   seqnames   start    end gene_ids                         gene_names           
#>   <fct>      <int>  <int> <chr>                            <chr>                
#> 1 1          10000 1.10e4 "ENSSSCG00000037372"             ""                   
#> 2 1          20000 2.10e4 "ENSSSCG00000037372"             ""                   
#> 3 1        1000000 1.00e6 ""                               ""                   
#> 4 2              0 1.00e5 "ENSSSCG00000014554, ENSSSCG000… "ODF3, RIC8A, SIRT3,…
```